# Hide UISplitview's masterDetailview programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am working on `UISplitview` base project.I have one problem regarding UISplitview.I want to hide masterDetailview (LeftSide view) in portrait mode form other `UIview controller` class .How can i do that ?

I declared UISplitviewcontroller in Appdelegate and create separate detail view class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial you will get your answer.

or try this

```
 - (BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc 
          inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation 
 {
     return YES;
  }
```

this for remove masterViewController

Comment: I implement all it but I want to hide masterdetailview(LeftSide view) from other class (UIViewcontroller).